# Banco SQL para vários usuários

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Bom, estou com uma dúvida. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que irá atender mais de um usuário, porém cada usuário tem diferentes dados gravados no banco, e este volume será grande, já que o sistema é para gestão de vendas.

Gostaria de saber como seria para eu fazer o banco da aplicação, colocar um `idUsuario` em cada item do banco e fazer as buscas filtrando por isto, ou tem alguma forma que traga mais performance para a aplicação?

Obrigado!

Comment: É Entity Framework? O MVC é ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: O que eu gostaria de saber é mais a nível de banco, mas a resposta é sim, para as duas perguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a maioria das consultas realizadas dentro do sistema envolverão o parâmetro de usuário, sim, você precisará parametrizar todas as tabelas com o `Id` do usuário, até porque é uma exigência de design do Entity Framework que seja desta forma.

Para auxiliar na parametrização das consultas sem você ter que preencher o usuário toda vez, [você pode usar o pacote NuGet `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/).

Comment: Eu já imagina, mas pensei muita na questão de que conforme o meu quantitativo de usuários for aumentando, uma tabela de produtos ou vendas, que serão as maiores do sistemas, a quantidade de dados nesta tabela, na hora de trazer somente os de um usuário não tornará a busca lenta? Eu estava procurando alguma forma de aumentar a performance.

Comment: Uma das formas seria colocar índices adicionais e estudar o plano das consultas mais recorrentes. Isto é feito de acordo com a tecnologia de banco de dados escolhida.